# Sharepoint 2010 WebParts Jquery Minimize Writing back to the WebPArt Manager

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I need my jquery expand and collapse code to actually write back to the Webpart Manager. Eg if a webpart has been minimized its state would be remembered. Eg if the page was refreshed the personnalized setting would be retained.

Theroy 1.

User a WCF service which would be call by the jquery code with the webparts id. The Wcf service would then simple just update the state of the webpart

Theory 2.
Call the same javascript function which sharepoint calls when minimize is selected. Been trying to find it appears to be

Any suggestions?

Comment: It appears to be .... what? If there's an out of the box function i'd say use that. Otherwise, WCF is an easily deployed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by building a WCF service which did the following;

the guid is the the webpart client id passed by the jquery ajax call, when the webpart is minimized

public string UpdateCurrentWebPart(string guidString)
        {

```
        SPWeb myweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        //only want the webparts with have personal settings
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = myweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("pages/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.User))
        {

            string result = "Not found " + guidString;

            //find my webpart
            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart _webpart in mgr.WebParts)
            {
                if (guidString.Contains(_webpart.ClientID))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //toggle it
                        if (_webpart.ChromeState == PartChromeState.Minimized)
                        {
                            _webpart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Normal;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _webpart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Minimized;

                        }

                        //save it
                        mgr.SaveChanges(_webpart);

                        //useful for debugging
                        result =  guidString + _webpart.ChromeState.ToString();

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }

                }


            }

            return result;

        }
```